# Unit test Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I am trying to paerform a unit test on my application and majority of the test failed and the reason it says is **Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 30 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Home Code".**

I do not know why it fails like this but this is my code below

```
class HomeTest: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
    }

    override func tearDown() {
    }

    func testHome() {
        let expec = expectation(description: "Home Code")
        let presenter =  HomePresenter(view: HomeTestVC(expectation: expec), source: Repository.instance)
        presenter.start()
        wait(for: [expec], timeout: 30)
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        self.measure {
        }
    }

}


class HomeTestVC: HomeContract.View {
    func showRatingForLastTrip(_ trip: Trip) {}

    func setProgress(enabled: Bool) {}

    func didFail(message: String) {}

    func didShowError(error: Error) {}

    func didShowStatusCode(code: Int?) {
        XCTAssertGreaterThan(200, code ?? 0)
        self.expec.fulfill()
    }

    var expec: XCTestExpectation
    init(expectation: XCTestExpectation) {
        self.expec = expectation
    }
}
```

It pops up the simulator but stays on just the first screen. I do not know why. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not **fulfilling** your expectations

```
func testExample() {
    let expec = expectation(description: "Home Code")
    someAsyncTask() { _ in 
       expectation.fulfill()
    }
    wait(for: [expec], timeout: 30)
}
```

See [Testing Asynchronous Operations with Expectations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations)

Notes:

- Don't pass unit test specific code to production code like you are currently.
- Loading a VC is not an async task. so shouldn't need an expectation
- You probably shouldn't be loading the Home class directly, especially if it does trigger some async task. You should look at testing the async parts seperately and using Mocks/Stubs

Comment: `let presenter =  HomePresenter(view: HomeTestVC(expectation: expec), source: Repository.instance)
        presenter.start()`   this is the async task. I am using an MVP architecture

Comment: `func didShowStatusCode(code: Int?) {
        XCTAssertGreaterThan(200, code ?? 0)
        self.expec.fulfill()
    }` I handled it here

Comment: NEVER run tests or test related code inside your production classes. XCTest library would not be linked in a non debug/test mode build for a start. you should TEST your production code, not modify your production code for test

Comment: This does not ran inside the production class. I only passed a value got in the asynchronous process into a function. That is why I shared the complete code.

Comment: `func didShowStatusCode(code: Int?)` is in production class and calls `fulfill`

Comment: it is in the `HomeContract.View` protocol. so extending this gives me access to the information there

Comment: Just like this https://github.com/omayib/TheRegistrationPage/blob/master/TheRegistrationPageTests/TheRegistrationPageTests.swift

Comment: some other test are successful while some fail

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now. Put a breakpoint in and see what it does. nothing in HomeTestVC calls didShowStatusCode

Comment: I created a MockViewController too `HomeTestVC`

Comment: nothing in HomeTestVC calls didShowStatusCode. add a breakpoint where your expectation is and it will never hit it. In the link that you shared, they call a method like register after setting presenter, so that something happens and calls delegate function

Comment: it works now but some still fail with this same error

Comment: You need to assess and fix each one.

Comment: Doing that now. Hope this issue is fixed

Answer (score 2):

### `waitForExpectations()` should come LAST

```
let exp = expectation(description: "wait for exp.fulfill()")

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    XCTAssertTrue(true)
    
    exp.fulfill()
}

waitForExpectations(timeout: 2) // make sure this comes after your assertions
```

Note: I had attempted to use `sleep(1)` to create a one second delay, but that doesn't really work with how Xcode tests are set up. Just use the dispatch queue `asyncAfter()` method if you need a delay, and make sure `waitForExpectations()` is called very last.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `fulfill` the expectation.  Like this:

```
let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Alert")

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0, execute: {

    expectation.fulfill()
})

waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)

XCTAssert(whatever)
```

Comment: this still gives the same fail

Comment: @King see my answer below (make sure `waitForExpectations()` comes last)